# Backend changes via Network Proxy GUI

Tags: unity, gui, proxy

I know the manual proxy can be setup using the network options in Ubuntu 14.04 and it works fine as posted in the link. What configuration files/environment variables change after saving setting via GUI?

[image: Proxy setup GUI dialog]